# Cocos2d-x project every time must compile the project plus other libraries

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, visual-studio

I'm using `cocos2d-x v3.6` for win32 desktop and `Visual Studio 2013` with c++.

When I change the code and then compile the project again, I must re-compile my project AND other libraries *every time* (e.g. libraries: `libbox2d` and `libcocos2d`), and this phase takes a *long* time.

I don't know why I get this bad behavior of having to re-compile the dependency libraries every time with the project.

**Is there is any way to change this bad behavior, to compile the project only without dependency libraries every time?**

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762930/vs2010-always-thinks-project-is-out-of-date-but-nothing-has-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest code to compile is the code that has not been written. If you don't intend to modify the libraries (which is the typical way to use 3rd party open source libraries), you should not include them in your solution.

You should compile them in a separate solution and make them available for your main project, whether they'll be statically linked or dynamically linked.

Another thing you could check, even if it's stating the obvious: when compiling, don't use "Rebuild Solution"; use "Build project".